# Calculating flow ith divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator, multiple-integral

The $B\subset \mathbb R ^3$ is the pyramid with the corner points $P(0,0,0),P(2,0,0),P(0,2,0)$ and $P(0,0,1)$.
The area $B$ is through the smooth surface $F$ limited.
Calculate the flow of a vector field $a=(x_3-x_1^2,2x_1-x_3,x_2-x_1)$ through $F$ using divergence theorem.

I did it like this:

$div a=-2x_1$

$\int_{0}^{2} \! \int_{0}^{2} \!\int_{0}^{1} \! -2x_1 \, dx_3   \, dx_2  \, dx_1 =-8$

Can someone say if this is good or not?

Comment: your limits of integration the suggest a rectilinear prism and not a pyramid.

Comment: @DougM Ok. Can you give me some hint, to how to get the right limits?

Comment: Your pyramid is bound by the planes $x=0, y=0, z=0$ and $x+y+2z = 2$

Comment: @DougM Should I use some other coordinates?

Comment: No. Integrate first for $x$ from $0$ to $2-2z-y$

Comment: @RafaBudría $\int_{0}^{1} \! \int_{0}^{2-2z} \! \int_{0}^{2-y-2z} \! -2x \, dx  \, dy  \, dz$  Is this correct?

Comment: That will work.

Comment: You got it perfectly.